# Change img src path by using NG-Model on <SELECT> tag

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-model

I'm new to AngularJS, I've started learning it since yesterday.

My HTML code:

```
<select ng-model="myImage">
        <option selected disabled>Make selection</option>
        <option value="earth">Earth</option>
        <option value="moon">Moon</option>
        <option value="sun">Sun</option>            
</select>

{{myImage}}
<img ng-src="{{myImage}}">
```

My JavaScript code:

```
(function() {
    app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller("imgController", function($scope) {          
        function getImageIdOrName(param) {  
            var imageNames = ["earth", "moon", "sun"];
            if (typeof param === "number") {
                return imageNames[param - 1];
            }
            if (typeof param === "string") {
                for (var i = 0; i <= imageNames.length; i++) {
                    if (imageNames[i] == param) {
                        return pad((i+1), 3);
                    }           
                }
            }
        }

        function pad(number, length) {   
            var str = '' + number;
            while (str.length < length) {
                str = '0' + str;
            }   
            return str;
        }

        $scope.myImage = "img/" + getImageIdOrName($scope.myImage) + "png";
   });
}());
```

I'm trying to display the image which is selected in the `<select>` tag, the images are named like:

`001.png` (Earth)
`002.png` (Moon)
`003.png` (Sun)

I know that I can fix this, by doing it like:

```
<select ng-model="myImage">
        <option selected disabled>Make selection</option>
        <option value="001">Earth</option>
        <option value="002">Moon</option>
        <option value="003">Sun</option>            
</select>

<img ng-src="img/{{myImage}}.png">
```

But what I really want to do is to pass names in the value of `<option>` instead of image IDs and then I want to use my `getImageIdOrName(param)` function to convert the name into ID and use the id for `<img>` tag's `src` attribute.

I've tried doing the following in my controller: `$scope.myImage = "img/" + getImageIdOrName($scope.myImage) + "png";`

But that doesn't seem to work, the `ng-model` is returning the selected value of `<option>` instead of doing`$scope.myImage = "img/" + getImageIdOrName($scope.myImage) + "png";`

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong and show me a solution for this?

Comment: Could you put your code in plunker?

Comment: I will try, I've never  used it before.

Comment: So are you gonna hardcode the options?

Comment: @ShamalPerera Yes, but I want the the value attribute of the <option> tag to have names instead of hardcoded ids.

Comment: I've no idea how to upload images to Plunker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is

```
<img ng-src="img/{{getImageIdOrName()}}.png">
```

Your code doesn't make much sense, because it initializes `$scope.myImage`only once, when the controller is instanciated. You need to get a new value each time the selection changes, and the easiest way to do that is to call the function from the view, as shown above.

Another option is to use `ng-change` on the select in order to invoke a function that changes the value of `myImage` every time the selection changes.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do this

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7tfYwO9Q8JW4GZScCxvK)

```
<select ng-model="myImage">
        <option selected disabled>Make selection</option>
        <option value="earth">Earth</option>
        <option value="moon">Moon</option>
        <option value="sun">Sun</option>            
</select>

{{myImage}}
<img ng-src="img/{{getImageIdOrName(myImage)}}.png">
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you did `$scope.getPokeIdOrName = getPokeIdOrName;` ?

Comment: If you want to access the method from html you will have to add it to the scope of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ui-select Here is a working plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/CsJoacczP3olTCxdgTzh?p=preview

```
<h3>Selectize theme</h3>
  <p>Selected: {{images.selected}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="image.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a image in the list...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="image in images | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="image.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
      <small ng-bind-html="image.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>

  {{ image }}
  <br/>
  <img ng-src="{{'img/' + image.selected.value + '.png'}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the ng-change event to the select box and pass the values to your method in the controller.

```js
(function() {
    app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller("imgController", function($scope) {          
        function getImageIdOrName(param) {  
            var imageNames = ["earth", "moon", "sun"];
            if (typeof param === "number") {
                return imageNames[param - 1];
            }
            if (typeof param === "string") {
                for (var i = 0; i <= imageNames.length; i++) {
                    if (imageNames[i] == param) {
                        return pad((i+1), 3);
                    }           
                }
            }
        }

        function pad(number, length) {   
            var str = '' + number;
            while (str.length < length) {
                str = '0' + str;
            }   
            return str;
        }
        //Function to be called whenever the values are changed in the select box
        $scope.updateImage = function(){
         $scope.myImage = "img/" + getImageIdOrName($scope.myImage) + ".png";        
        }

   });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="imgController">
<select ng-model="myImage" ng-change="updateImage(myImage)">
        <option selected disabled>Make selection</option>
        <option value="earth">Earth</option>
        <option value="moon">Moon</option>
        <option value="sun">Sun</option>            
</select>

{{myImage}}
<img ng-src="{{myImage}}">
</div>
```